# I need to know why this is the output for these python condition

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
numbers=[i**3 for i in range (10) if i**3%3==1]
print(numbers)
#gets 1,64,343
```

Why is `1, 64, 343` the answer?

Comment: Do you know what `**` does?  Do you know what `%` does?  If not, have you looked at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)?

Comment: **3 means you have to multiply same number 3 times like 3x3x3

Comment: Because 1, 64, and 343 are the only cubes of the numbers from 0 to 9 that are also one greater than a multiple of three.

Comment: Brenbarn... here's what I was doing. I cant figure out why the answer for the last one is 1,64 & 343(evens=[i**2 for i in range(10) if i**2 % 2 == 0]
print(evens)
#so this results 0,4,16,36,64
odds=[i**3 for i in range(10) if i**3%3==0]
print(odds)
#so this one gets 0,27,216,729
#0x0x0=0
#3x3x3=27
#6x6x6=216
#9x9x9=729
numbers=[i**3 for i in range (10) if i**3%3==1]
print(numbers)
#gets 1,64,343)

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to the code:

```
for i in range(10):
    if (i*i*i) % 3 == 1:
         numbers.append(i*i*i)
print (numbers)
```

You are checking if the remainder obtained when the cube of a number from 1 to 10 is divided by 3 is equal to 1. If it is, you are adding it to a list and printing it.

Comment: He has appended i*i*i to the list whereas I appended i to the list. I have changed that now.

Answer (score 1):

first `i` is in `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
then if `(i*i*i) rem 3` is equal to `1`
it selects `(i*i*i)`
and for [1,4,7]:  `(1*1*1)%3==1`, `(4*4*4)%3==1` and `(7*7*7)%3==1`:
1*1*1=1 and 1/3=0 :remainder=1
4*4*4=64 and 64/3=21 :remainder=1
7*7*7=343 and 343/3=114 :remainder=1

so the output is:
[1*1*1, 4*4*4, 7*7*7] which is  [1, 64, 343]

your code:

```
numbers=[i**3 for i in range (10) if i**3%3==1]
print(numbers)
```

and this code:

```
numbers=[]
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
    if (i*i*i) % 3 == 1:
         numbers.append(i*i*i)
print(numbers)
```

output this:

```
[1, 64, 343]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The meaning of `**`
     ex: `2**3`= `2*2*2` `#this means 2 to the power 3 = 8`
2. The meaning of `%`
     ex: `5%2`= `1` `#the sign means module, that means the remaining value after divide 5 by 2, it is one.`

in your way, the correct path to write the for each is

```
for i in range(0,10):
    value = i**3
    if(value%3 == 1):
        print("the value is {0}".format(value))
```

so the result is :

```
the value is 1
the value is 64
the value is 343
```

## bit explanation inside the for loop

- first get the `i = 0`, at this point `value = 0*0*0 = 0`, then `value%3=0`
- then get the `i=1`, at this point `value = 1*1*1 = 1` ,the 'value%3' means `1%3 = 1`, so the answer i `1`

.... like this see about other conditions also. hope this will help to you.

Comment: I think this is the answer im looking for anuradh. Thx.  Ill go back to your exzmple in a bit